# Confused about how to reshape my data, column for each day

Tags: matlab

I am pulling in a file which contains two columns. My first column is a timestamp column, with the date/time being indexed every minute over the course of 30 days. My second column is my data column, where each row corresponds to the value logged at that minute from the Time Stamp.

My goal is to reshape my data so that each day is in it's own column, as shown by the diagram below. The "Current" is what my data currently looks like. The "Goal" is what I would like my dataset to look like, and I am having trouble figuring out how to get there.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: When you write "every minute over the course of 30 days" it means you have essentially 60*24*30 rows, right? In this case, wouldn't `reshape(data(:,2),[60*24,30])` be what you need?

Comment: I can try that.  Do you think it would produce the array like I have in my photo under "Goal"?  How would I split each column by day, like I have above?

Comment: `reshape(data(:,2),[60*24,30])` gives an array with 60*24 rows (each row corresponding to one minute of the day) and 30 columns (each column corresponding to one day). Is that what you want?

Comment: Yep!  That sounds about right!  Feel free to write an Answer, and I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write "every minute over the course of 30 days", which means you have essentially 60*24*30 rows. In this case, what you need to do is simply `reshape(data(:,2),[60*24,30])`. This gives an array with 60*24 rows (each row corresponding to one minute of the day) and 30 columns (each column corresponding to one day).